# Duda con Java 8 (oracle) Netbeans

Tags: oracle, netbeans

estoy por empezar a programar en c++ y en un tutorial de instalación respecto a netbeans(IDE), dicen que debo instalar javaJDK o JAVA8 (oracle) para luego instalar NETBEANS, mi duda es la siguiente, 
**¿para que me sirve tener java8 (oracle) o javajdk?** **¿son obligatorios?.** Gracias :D

Comment: netbeans es una IDE escrita en java, sin java no puedes usar la interface.

Comment: gracias!; sabes que diferencia hay entre ambas?, "javajdk y java 8?.

Comment: Jdk es el kit de desarrollo de Java. Java 8 es la versión de Java que se pide

Answer (score 1):

### JDK te sirve para programar, y java8 par ejecutar aplicaciones basadas en java.

JDK es el entorno de desarrollo, y java8 la última versión de java. Te hacen falta ambas para programar en java y ejecutar NETBEANS (IDE basada en java).

Con java8, además, puedes desarrollar aplicaciones para versiones anteriores (indicándolo explícitamente en las propiedades del proyecto).

Answer (score 0):

El JDK es el Java Development Kit. Lo necesitas para poder programar, ya que te proporciona las herramientas para ello. Si vas a utilizar NetBeans (programado en Java), necesitas además instalar JRE.